# Suggestions for better code in python way of searching a string using regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of code for searching a specific block of address and formatting the results in a certain way.

e.g, I have an input string "70D76320 BEG 701D135D 702D72FC END EAR0 00000000 0000000". I need to extract addresses between "BEG" and "END" which are "701D135D" and "702D72FC" in this case and format them in the following fashion:

```
[0]0x701D135D  
[1]0x702D72FC
```

I wrote a script for that purpose:

```
import re
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--address', help='Parse the input addresses')
args = parser.parse_args()
addressInfo = args.address

filter = re.compile(r'(BEG )((\w{8})\s)+(END )')
btInfo = filter.search(addressInfo)

print ("\n")
addresses = btInfo.group().split()
for idx in range(len(addresses)):
    if((addresses[idx] != 'BEG') and (addresses[idx] != 'END')):
        print ("[%d]0x%s" %(idx-1, addresses[idx]))
```

When I review the code, it more like c/c++ code than python. Is there a better way the achieve the same result in the 'real python style'？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without `re`, but `split()` and with `enumerate()` for indexes:

```
def get_addresses(input_string):
    for address in input_string.split(' BEG ')[-1].split(' END ')[0].split(' '):
        yield address

foo = "70D76320 BEG 701D135D 702D72FC END EAR0 00000000 0000000"
for idx, address in enumerate(get_addresses(foo)):
    print(f'[{idx}]0x{address}')
```

- using f-strings requires 3.6+

Comment: This is really cool, thanks. But I got a question. Is there performance for using co-routine to yield over using a for loop to get a single element one by one from the split results? e.g  using `for index, address in enumerate(addressInfo.split("BEG ")[-1].split(" END")[0].split()):` instead of using `def get_address(input_string)`

Comment: in this particular case (assuming you will not have many addresses) there is no practical difference. In general case split() will produce list in memory, while get_addresses is generator and it will not produce the whole list in the memory. In addition it makes the code more structured and allows to test the generator function separately. You can read more about generators here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Actually, I was corrected (outside SO) that `str.split()` will create the list in memory in any case, so this particular part of my previous comment is nor correct. still the code is better structured and easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import re
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--address', help='Parse the input addresses')
addressInfo = parser.parse_args().address

btInfo = re.search(r' BEG (.*?) END ', addressInfo).group(1)
print("\n")

for index, address in enumerate(btInfo.split()):
    print("[{0}]0x{1}".format(index, address))
```

`r'BEG (.*?) END '` will get everything between `BEG` and `END`. And by using `eumerate()` in the for-loop, you can loop through the split string and keep track of the index at the same time.

The code will give the following output:

```
[0]0x701D135D  
[1]0x702D72FC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search` with Lookbehind & Lookahead and grouping.

**Ex**

```
import re

s = "70D76320 BEG 701D135D 702D72FC END EAR0 00000000 0000000"
m = re.search(r"(?<=\bBEG\b)(?P<address_1>.+) (?P<address_2>.+)(?=\bEND\b)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group("address_1").strip())
    print(m.group("address_2").strip())
```

**Output:**

```
701D135D
702D72FC
```

Comment: The reason that using the `re.findall with Lookbehind & Lookahead` better than using `re.search` is?

Comment: You do not need to iterate your data to fetch all the values.

Comment: Is you data just one line? `"70D76320 BEG 701D135D 702D72FC END EAR0 00000000 0000000".`? or do you have multiple lines?

Comment: The input is a one line string

Comment: Updated snippet.